# IF Statement for SharePoint calculated columns comparing months

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I'm Trying to display dates in a calculated column in the format of "DD - DD Month Year" (05-10 August 2018) or as "DD Month - DD Month Year" (30 August - 03 September 2018) if the Months are different.

I know the formula for both.

first is:

```
=CONCATENATE(text([Start Time],"dd"),"-", text([End Time], "DD"), " ", text([End Time], "mmmm"), " ", text([End Time], "yyyy"))
```

Sencond is:

```
=CONCATENATE(text([Start Time],"dd"), " ", text([Start Time], "mmmm"),"-", text([End Time], "DD"), " ", text([End Time], "mmmm"), " ", text([End Time], "yyyy"))
```

I tried making an IF statement but i cant get it to work.

```
=IF(Month[Start Time] = Month[End Time], =CONCATENATE(text([Start Time],"dd"),"-", text([End Time], "DD"), " ", text([End Time], "mmmm"), " ", text([End Time], "yyyy")), =CONCATENATE(text([Start Time],"dd"), " ", text([Start Time], "mmmm"),"-", text([End Time], "DD"), " ", text([End Time], "mmmm"), " ", text([End Time], "yyyy")))
```

Please advise how show the dates in specified format?

Comment: Hi @JinBrau, don't forget to accept the helpful answer as the best answer. It will also help others in the forum to get the answer quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main issue in the true and false section! where you added additional **equal =** like `=CONCATENATE`

Try to remove **equal =** before `CONCATENATE` and use the below formula that should be working properly

**Formula**

```
=IF(Month([Start Time]) = Month([End Time]), CONCATENATE(text([Start Time],"dd"),"-", text([End Time], "DD"), " ", text([End Time], "mmmm"), " ", text([End Time], "yyyy")), CONCATENATE(text([Start Time],"dd"), " ", text([Start Time], "mmmm"),"-", text([End Time], "DD"), " ", text([End Time], "mmmm"), " ", text([End Time], "yyyy")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Need "()" in `MONTH([column])` function.

Summary:

```
IF(MONTH([Start Time]) = MONTH([End Time]), CONCATENATE(text([Start Time],"dd"),"-", text([End Time], "DD"), " ", text([End Time], "mmmm"), " ", text([End Time], "yyyy")), CONCATENATE(text([Start Time],"dd"), " ", text([Start Time], "mmmm"),"-", text([End Time], "DD"), " ", text([End Time], "mmmm"), " ", text([End Time], "yyyy")))
```